# AEM Query builder exclude a folder in search

Tags: search, aem, query-builder

I need to create a query where the params are like:

```
queryParams.put("path", "/content/myFolder");
queryParams.put("1_property", "myProperty");
queryParams.put("1_property.operation", "exists");
queryParams.put("p.limit", "-1");
```

But, I need to exclude a certain path inside this blanket folder , say: `"/content/myFolder/wrongFolder"` and search in all other folders (whose number keeps on varying)

Is there a way to do so ? I didn't find it exactly online.

I also tried the `unequals` operation as the parent path is being saved in a JCR property, but still no luck. I actually need `unlike` to avoid all occurrences of the path. But there is no such thing:

```
path=/main/path/to/search/in
group.1_property=cq:parentPath
group.1_property.operation=unequals
group.1_property.value=/path/to/be/avoided
group.2_property=myProperty
group.2_property.operation=exists
group.p.or=true
p.limit=-1
```

Comment: if SQL2 query will work for you then you can execute as this query : select * from [nt:unstructured] as p
            where
               (isdescendantnode (p, [/content/myFolder/])
               AND NOT isdescendantnode (p, [/content/myFolder/wrongFolder/]))
                         and contains(p.*, 'myProperty') Let me know if this works.

Comment: @SumantaPakira, I cannot use SQL2 for now, as it will need a major change in the application. Hence, looking for a solution only within query builder for now.

Answer (score 1):

Using QueryBuilder you can execute:

```
map.put("group.p.not",true)
map.put("group.1_path","/first/path/where/you/donot/want/to/search")
map.put("group.2_path","/second/path/where/you/donot/want/to/search")
```

Also I've checked PredicateGroup's class API and they provide a `setNegated` method. I've never used it myself, but I think you can negate a group and combine it into a common predicate with the path you are searching on like:

```
final PredicateGroup doNotSearchGroup = new PredicateGroup();
doNotSearchGroup.setNegated(true);
doNotSearchGroup.add(new Predicate("path").set("path", "/path/where/you/donot/want/to/search"));

final PredicateGroup combinedPredicate = new PredicateGroup();
combinedPredicate.add(new Predicate("path").set("path", "/path/where/you/want/to/search"));
combinedPredicate.add(doNotSearchGroup);

final Query query = queryBuilder.createQuery(combinedPredicate);
```

Comment: The group.p.not did not work for me. I tried below and got thrice the results than earlier.: 
path=/main/path/where/I/want/to/search
group.p.not=true
group.1_path=/first/path/where/you/donot/want/to/search
group.2_property=myProperty
group.2_property.operation=exists
group.p.or=true
p.limit=-1

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but the reason you got more results later lies in the way in which you have constructed your query. The correct way to write a query like this would be something like:

```
path=/main/path/where
property=myProperty
property.operation=exists
property.value=true
group.p.or=true
group.p.not=true
group.1_path=/main/path/where/first/you/donot/want/to/search
group.2_path=/main/path/where/second/you/donot/want/to/search
p.limit=-1
```

A couple of notes: your group.p.or in your last comment would have applied to all of your groups because they weren't delineated by a group number. If you want an OR to be applied to a specific group (but not all groups), you would use:

```
path=/main/path/where
group.1_property=myProperty
group.1_property.operation=exists
group.1_property.value=true
2_group.p.or=true
2_group.p.not=true
2_group.3_path=/main/path/where/first/you/donot/want/to/search
2_group.4_path=/main/path/where/second/you/donot/want/to/search
```

Also, the numbers themselves don't matter - they don't have to be sequential, as long as property predicate numbers aren't reused, which will cause an exception to be thrown when the QB tries to parse it. But for readability and general convention, they're usually presented that way.

I presume that your example was just thrown together for this question, but obviously your "do not search" paths would have to be children of the main path you want to search or including them in the query would be superfluous, the query would not be searching them anyway otherwise.

[AEM Query Builder Documentation for 6.3](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-api.html)

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: 2_group.p.or=true is not setting OR condition to group 2. Can you give me correct syntax ? If possible could you please look into - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489052/how-to-specify-nested-not-operation-in-specific-group-id-in-aem

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query to specify operator on given specific group id.

```
path=/content/course/
type=cq:Page
p.limit=-1
1_property=jcr:content/event

group.1_group.1_group.daterange.lowerBound=2019-12-26T13:39:19.358Z
group.1_group.1_group.daterange.property=jcr:content/xyz

group.1_group.2_group.daterange.upperBound=2019-12-26T13:39:19.358Z
group.1_group.2_group.daterange.property=jcr:content/abc

group.1_group.3_group.relativedaterange.property=jcr:content/courseStartDate
group.1_group.3_group.relativedaterange.lowerBound=0
group.1_group.2_group.p.not=true
group.1_group.1_group.p.not=true
```