# How to specify nested “not” operation in specific group id in AEM?

Tags: xpath, aem, query-builder, predicate

I have a little complex predicator  in which I need to have some nested not operation

```
path=/content/course/
type=cq:Page
group.1_daterange.lowerBound=2019-06-12T13:39:19.358Z
group.1_daterange.property=jcr:content/xyz

group.2_daterange.upperBound=2019-06-12T13:39:19.358Z
group.2_daterange.property=jcr:content/abc

group.3_relativedaterange.property=jcr:content/courseStartDate
group.3_relativedaterange.lowerBound=0
group.p.not=true
```

I don’t want to include the result of group 1 and group 2 hence I am using NOT operation, unfortunately  this works at root level, not at level group(n) level. Basically I need to set not operation for group 1 and group 2, like `not(group 1 & group 2) and group 3` Is there any syntax which will do suite my case ?

I tried with below syntax but it is simply ignoring it.

```
group.1_group.p.not=true
group.2_group.p.not=true
```

Comment: What about SQL2 instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the first two predicates in one group and then apply NOT only to that group. Does the below query work for you?

```
path=/content/course/
type=cq:Page
1_group.1_daterange.lowerBound=2019-06-12T13:39:19.358Z
1_group.1_daterange.property=jcr:content/xyz
1_group.2_daterange.upperBound=2019-06-12T13:39:19.358Z
1_group.2_daterange.property=jcr:content/abc
1_group.p.not=true

2_group.1_relativedaterange.property=jcr:content/courseStartDate
2_group.1_relativedaterange.lowerBound=0
```