# Exclude child path from fulltext search parent path using Querybuilder OR get search hit excerpt from XPATH/JCR SQL2 query

Tags: lucene, aem, query-builder, jackrabbit-oak, jcr-sql2

I want to exclude child nodes path from search path using querybuilder

for example - parent folder is /content/mysite/en

and subfolders are

/content/mysite/en/testfolder1

/content/mysite/en/testfolder2

I want query builder to write a query to exclude these paths

I already looked at this question -

[AEM Query builder exclude a folder in search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292778/aem-query-builder-exclude-a-folder-in-search)

but grouping paths and p.not=true doesn't seem to be working as expected

I know it's a bit tricky to write such a query using query builder ; so I am using JCR/SQL2 query  -

using

```
SELECT * FROM [cq:Page] 
WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(page,'/content/mysite/en') 
AND CONTAINS(*, 'fulltext') 
AND NOT ISDESCENDANTNODE(page, '/content/mysite/en/testfolder1') 
AND NOT ISDESCENDANTNODE(page, '/content/mysite/en/testfolder2')
```

but the issue now is that We also want the search excerpt which is created automatically by querybuilder api's SearchResult's hit object -

```
hit.getExcerpt()
```

so is there a way I can get the excerpt using JCR/SQL2 query ?

OR is there a way I can build the exclude subfolder query using querybuilder; so that I can get excerpts from results? Both solutions will solve my case.

If anyone has experience in excluding subfolder query using querybuilder; or building search excerpt using JCR/SQL2 query; or any other idea/suggestion for this case;  help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try path.exact=true Below is a example

without path.exact=true

```
type=cq:Page
path=/content/wkndmuzik/us/en
```

output:
[image]

With path.exact=true

```
type=cq:Page
path=/content/wkndmuzik/us/en
path.exact=true
```

Output:
[image]

path.exact=true : If true exact path is matched, if false all descendants are included.

For other predicates on querybuider api visit the [blog of Hashim Khan](https://hashimkhan.in/2015/12/02/query-builder/)